# Split records based on date in sql

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, join, union

> ID EFF_DT END_DT
>
> FLA1 2018-01-01 00:00:00 2019-12-31 00:00:00
>
> FLA1 2020-01-01 00:00:00 9999-12-31 00:00:00

The above structure needs to be splited. And the split should be based on the date.

the output should have additional column as year

> ID EFF_DT END_DT YEAR
>
> FLA1 2018-01-01 00:00:00 2019-12-31 00:00:00 2019
>
> FLA1 2020-01-01 00:00:00 2020-12-31 00:00:00 2020
>
> FLA1 2021-01-01 00:00:00 9999-12-31 00:00:00 2021

I am using union for this purpose and it is generating duplicates. Any other approach / refine solution will work. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why is the 2nd row (from the "above structure") split into two? Why not into 9999 - 2020 = 7979 rows? Which rules lead from input to desired output?

Comment: the previous year should be record 1 , record 2 should be the current one and the record 3 should be the future one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a recursive sub-query factoring clause:

```sql
WITH split ( ID, EFF_DT, END_DT, MAX_DT ) AS (
  SELECT id, 
         eff_dt,
         LEAST(
           ADD_MONTHS( TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'YY' ), 12 ) - INTERVAL '1' DAY,
           end_dt
         ),
         end_dt
  FROM   table_name
UNION ALL
  SELECT id,
         end_dt + INTERVAL '1' DAY,
         max_dt,
         max_dt
  FROM   split
  WHERE  end_dt < max_dt
)
SELECT id,
       eff_dt,
       end_dt
FROM   split;
```

Which, for your sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( ID, EFF_DT, END_DT ) AS
SELECT 'FLA1', DATE '2018-01-01', DATE '2019-12-31' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'FLA1', DATE '2020-01-01', DATE '9999-12-31' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> ID   | EFF_DT              | END_DT             
> :--- | :------------------ | :------------------
> FLA1 | 2018-01-01 00:00:00 | 2019-12-31 00:00:00
> FLA1 | 2020-01-01 00:00:00 | 2020-12-31 00:00:00
> FLA1 | 2021-01-01 00:00:00 | 9999-12-31 00:00:00
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=c0cc167f136690fb8732f68e294f29e0)*

Answer (score 0):

If you want to generate *all* years of data, then:

```
with cte (id, eff_dt, end_dt, orig_end_dt)
      select id, eff_dt, end_dt, end_dt
      from t
      union all
      select cte.id, end_dt + interval '1' day,
             least(orig_end_dte, trunc(end_dt, 'YYYY') + interval '1' year
      from cte
      where trunc(eff_dt, 'YYYY') < trunc(end_dt, 'YYYY')
     )
select id, eff_dt, end_dt, to_char(end_dt, 'YYYY') as year
from cte;
```

Note:  This produces a separate row for *every* year in the period.

If you want a limit on the year, then it would be something like this:

```
with cte (id, eff_dt, end_dt, orig_end_dt)
      select id, eff_dt, end_dt, end_dt
      from t
      union all
      select cte.id, end_dt + interval '1' day,
             least(orig_end_dte, trunc(end_dt, 'YYYY') + interval '1' year
      from cte
      where trunc(eff_dt, 'YYYY') < least(trunc(end_dt, 'YYYY'), date '2021-01-01')
     )
select id, eff_dt,
       (case when end_dt = date '2021-12-31' then orig_end_dt else end_dt end),
       to_char(end_dt, 'YYYY') as year
from cte;
```